# Forward error for a triangular system

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not know how to prove the formula of forward error analysis for a triangular system(attached):

[image]

Also I do not know how to compute the norm when there is absolute values in it like the $\mathrm{cond}(T,x)$.

Comment: Where is this from? What are theorems 8.5 and 7.4? Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Proof can be found in Higham, Nicholas J. Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms. Siam, 2002.

You have cited a fragment of this book, which part of the proof is unclear to you?

General strategy to prove (8.2) is:

1. compute componentwise forward error for general linear system
2. compute backward error for triangular linear system

In Higham's book you may also find efficient way to compute required condition numbers:

1. In order to compute $\||A||x|\|_\infty$, where A is a matrix and x is a vector, one can use the identity
   $$\||A||x|\|_\infty = \|A X\|_\infty$$
   where $X = diag(|x|)$ is the diagonal matrix with $|x|$ on the main diagonal.
2. The p-norm of a matrix A can be estimated using iterative method, see for example [1] William W. Hager, "Condition Estimates," SIAM J. Sci. Stat. Comput. 5, 1984, 311-316, 1984; [2] Nicholas J. Higham and Françoise Tisseur, "A Block Algorithm for Matrix 1-Norm Estimation with an Application to 1-Norm Pseudospectra, "SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl., Vol. 21, 1185-1201, 2000. 
   This method requires evaluation of matrix-vector product only, i.e. $Az$ and $A^Tz$ for appropriately constructed vector $z$.
3. Using these two tools in order to evaluate $cond(T,x)$ and $cond(T)$ (called Skeel condition numbers) one only needs to compute $|T|z$, $|T^T|z$ and solve linear systems $T^{-1}z$, $(T^{-1})^Tz$ for appropriate vectors z; explicit construction of the matrix $T^{-1}$ is not required.